# Apache not serving pages stored in Subversion repository

Tags: apache-http-server, svn

I've setup Apache and Subversion on an old PC, but Apache is not serving pages correctly, when I enter the address to my test site:

```
http://HOME_IP_ADDRESS/test/index.html
```

I just get a File Not Found error and the following output in the error log:

```
File does not exist: /var/www/html/svn/repos/test
```

but I know the file exists, when I enter the following URL into the browser:

```
 http://HOME_IP_ADDRESS/repos/test/index.html
```

I just get a listing of the HTML. In my Apache config file I have the Document Root set as follows:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/svn/repos"
```

so I'm not sure what is going on, I have SVN installed and I think it may have something to do this.

- Edit *

I changed the Document Root location, which helped as pages in the new location were served correctly, so the problem is with just serving the pages from the repository.

Comment: Can you post the output from `sudo apachectl -S`

Comment: Try it with a trailing slash like this `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/svn/repos/"`

Comment: @heavyd VirtualHost configuration:
Syntax OK

Comment: @MonkeyZeus just tried it with the extra forward slash, but made no difference.

Comment: Any luck with this? Did you try un-installing SVN and seeing if it made a difference? If you change `DocumentRoot` to something completely different like `/var/www/new_html/projects/a_project/` then does it have any effect at all?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Changing the Document Root location seemed to make a difference, I'll try uninstalling SVN tonight and reinstall in a different location and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Nice! let me know how it goes

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I followed these instructions: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Subversion when installing subversion. I don't want to go uninstalling without trying to fix it first. Any thoughts as to why it might not work.

Comment: I have never setup Subversion before but I've taken a look at the documentation and maybe I am not understanding something but it seems like SVN needs to run on it's own server with Apache because the URLs seem to be customized to perform SVN functions/actions. This SVN server would push files to your web server if I am not mistaken. The thing that caught my eye the most is `5.1. Layout Your Repo` and the project tree which they layout. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @CharlieRB I'm not sure why this was closed, surely Subversion and Apache come under the 'Computer Software' heading as mentioned in the help center. I see lots of other questions relating to Apache.

Comment: Question reopened. Not sure what close voters were thinking here. Please [edit] your question and include all the additional info found in the comments in the actual question (like `apachectl` output, that you tried uninstalling, what instructions you followed). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it with a bit of help from a colleague in work and also from MonkeyZeus above.

Firstly, the SVN repository should not be installed in the Document Root location. While the instructions here (http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Subversion) are not actually wrong, its a bit misleading.

Apache cannot serve the pages directly from the SVN repository. So I had to checkout the files from the repository into the Document Root folder.

So when I'm working on my local copy in Eclipse on my laptop, I save the changes and commit the changes.

I then log onto my server, navigate to the Document Root and type the command:

```
svn st -u
```

this tells me what files in the Document Root need to update as they are different than what is in the repository.

To update the files I type:

```
svn update
```

and that's it.

Thanks to MonkeyZeus for your assistance, it helped get me in the right direction.